# Python subprocess.check_output('adb devices') return none

Tags: python, android, subprocess

Sorry for my poor English.Please try to understand that!

The call to `subprocess.check_output('adb devices')` return none
But in the window of CMD implementation ADB devices can normally display the connected phone, I don't know why

System: Window 10
Python: 3.7.7

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.check_output('adb devices',shell=True)
print(process)   # return b''
```

The same goes for subprocess.check_output(['adb','devices'],shell=True)

In addition, when executing
`subprocess.check_output(['adb','--version'],shell=True)`, # return b''

But when I execute `subprocess.check_output(['adb','--help'],shell=True)`, I get the information

```
# b'Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41\r\nVersion 29.0.5-5949299\r\nInstalled as ...
```

Output:

```
E:\Server-test>adb devices
List of devices attached
UQG0220430012553        device
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4j9k.png)

I also tried os.popen() and other methods, but they all ended up calling subprocess.popen (), and I called subprocess.popen () directly to get the same result

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the `check_output` method, your command look like this:

```
process = subprocess.check_output(['adb', 'devices'])
```

If you want to also capture any possible error messages you can also do:

```
process = subprocess.check_output(['adb', 'devices'], stderr=SDTOUT)
```

Comment: process = subprocess.check_output(['adb', 'devices'], stderr=SDTOUT)
The result is again None

Comment: I redescribed the problem I encountered above

Comment: Try passing the full path to the adb executable. It's possible that it's not being found